# Problem 5, Chapter 3 from Stein and Shakarchi's "Real Analysis" on a version of the FTC

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The problem reads:

> Suppose that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $F'(x)$ exists for *every* $x\in(a,b)$, and $F'(x)$ is integrable. Then $F$ is absolutely continuous and
>   $$F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b F'(x)\,dx.$$
>   [Hint: Assume $F'(x)\geq 0$ for a.e. $x$. We want to conclude that $F(b)\geq F(a)$. Let $E$ be the set of measure zero of those $x$ such that $F'(x)<0$. Then according to Exercise 25, there is a function $\Phi$ which is increasing, absolutely continuous, and for which $(D^+\Phi)(x)=+\infty$, $x\in E$. Consider $F+\delta\Phi$ for each $\delta$ and apply the result (a) in Exercise 23.]

Result (a) in Exercise 23 is that if $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $(D^+F)(x)\geq 0$ for every $x\in[a,b]$ then $F$ is increasing on $[a,b]$. S&S have defined
$$(D^+F)(x)=\limsup_{h\to 0^+} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}.$$

**My question:** I am able to prove what they suggest in the hint, but I don't see how it connects to the original problem. Why can I assume that $F'(x)\geq 0$ for a.e. $x$? And even then, knowing $F(b)-F(a)\geq 0$ is a far cry from knowing its exact value. Rudin proves this theorem in Chapter 7 of his "Real and Complex Analysis" by an entirely different proof, but I would like to understand what S&S are suggesting here. Any reference or hint is welcome.

Comment: I think that the assumption about $F'(x)\ge 0$ is just to simplify the proof in some way, so you can see $F$ as a monotone function. Possibly after you do this proof you can generalize the result for non-monotone continuous functions just dividing the function on intervals where is monotone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether this is exactly the solution they had in mind, because we need something that's sort of not *quite* the same as the hint. But it's very much like the hint. (And I'm glad you asked the question, because I never remember anything except things I've figured out myself - now I finally know a proof of this fact.)

The hint amounts to this:

**Hint** If $F$ is differentiable and $F'\ge0$ almost everywhere then $F$ is increasing.

We need the fact that $F$ is differentiable *everywhere* to show that $D^+(F+\delta\Phi)\ge 0$ everywhere; for example we know the following is false:

**False Fact** If $F$ is continuous, differentiable almost everywhere, and satisfies $F'\ge0$ almost everywhere then $F$ is increasing.

We're going to use a stronger version of the hint:

**Lemma** Suppose $F$ is continuous, $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere, $F'\ge0$ almost everywhere, and $D^+F>-\infty$ *everywhere*. Then $F$ is increasing.

Proof: The fact that $D^+F>-\infty$ shows that $D^+(F+\delta\Phi)\ge0$ everywhere, for every $\delta>0$. So $F+\delta\Phi$ is increasing, and letting $\delta\to0$ shows that $F$ is increasing. QED.

Solution to the exercise: First, of course we may assume that $F$ is real-valued. Define $$G(x)=\int_a^x(F'(t))^+\,dt.$$Then $G$ is absolutely continuous and $G'=(F')^+$ almost everywhere. Let $$H=G-F.$$Then $H'=(F')^+-F'=(F')^-\ge0$ almost everywhere. And since $G$ is increasing and $F$ is differentiable it follows that $D^+H>-\infty$ everywhere. So the lemma shows that $H$ is increasing.

Now $H(b)\ge H(a)$ shows that $$F(b)-F(a)\le G(b)-G(a)=\int_a^b(F')^+.$$Applying this with $-F$ in place of $F$ shows that $$F(a)-F(b)\le\int_a^b(F')^-.$$But $|F(b)-F(a)|$ is either $F(b)-F(a)$ oor $F(a)-F(b)$. So we have $$|F(b)-F(a)|\le\int_a^b|F'|.$$

And now we're done. If $a_1<b_1<\dots<a_n<b_n$ then the same argument shows that $$\sum|F(b_n)-F(a_n)|\le\sum\int_{a_n}^{b_n}|F'|.$$Since $F'\in L^1$ this shows that $F$ is absolutely continuous. QED